# How can I enable or disable a windows service in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

How can I enable or disable a windows service in .NET? What do I have to know: its name or some kind of its id? In particular, in Windows 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable or disable it by its name like

```
sc config <your_service_name> start= disabled
```

However if you are looking for a programmatic way then you can try this:

```
    using (var m = new ManagementObject($"Win32_Service.Name=\"{serviceName}\""))
    {
        m.InvokeMethod("ChangeStartMode", new object[] { "Automatic" });
    }
```

Please check [ChangeStartMode method of the Win32_Service class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384896(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: That's some funny looking c#.

Comment: @spender:- I have added the C# code. I was not sure if OP was looking for a C# way.

Comment: does it have to be run from the admin account?

Comment: and how to stop a service?

Comment: @OskarK.:- Just make the parameter as `Disabled` instead of `Automatic` :)

Comment: disabled and stop isn't the same thing.

Comment: actually, if you need stop/start/pause/resume/obtain status , there is good class System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController in System.ServiceProcess namespace

Comment: does the code have to be run from the admin account?

Comment: does the code have to be run from the admin account?

Comment: @OskarK.:- Yes, you have to run it using the admin account or the user should have admin rights.